# Erro em eliminar cookie - PHP

Tags: php

- Caros, esta pergunta náo é duplicada. Pelo menos, pesquisei muito no fórum e náo encontrei nada parecido. O que vocês estáo dizendo é que o comando "header" náo funciona quando há uma saída anterior. No meu caso, o que existe sáo somente os comandos "unset"e "setcookie". Podem rever as respostas, por favor? Muito obrigado *

Amigos, fiz um sisteminha para uso pessoal em que um cookie determina se o usuário está logado. Não é uma session, mas funciona belezinha.

O problema aparece quando tento "deslogar".

O código está assim:

```
<?php
    unset($_COOKIE['lcon_mail']);
    setcookie('lcon_mail', null, -1, '/');
?>
```

E quando executo, ao invés de apagar o cookie, ele retorna esta mensagem:

*Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/mononoco/public_html/lcon/bd_sair.php:1) in /home1/mononoco/public_html/lcon/bd_sair.php on line 3*

Alguém pode ajudar a resolver, por favor? Obrigado

Comment: Duplicata de [Erro - “Cannot modify header information - headers already sent”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/5878)

Comment: Fora isso recomendo rever o seu sistema de autenticação. O cookie fica armazenado no navegador do usuário e pode ser facilmente alterado por ele manualmente.

Comment: você não pode setar ou remover cookies se tiver qualquer saida do seu php para tela do usuario. tenta colocar isso na primeira linha ou monta uma tela so para apagar o cookie que redireciona para tela de login por ex

Comment: @Woss session cria um cookie como identificação e também pode ser alterado manualmente

Comment: Sim é duplicada.O aviso é claro, os cookies são enviados no cabeçalho da resposta HTTP. Como o conteúdo HTML já foi iniciado, você não pode voltar ao cabeçalho e modificar o cookie. Leia [setcookie](https://www.php.net/setcookie): **setcookie () define um cookie a ser enviado junto com o restante dos cabeçalhos HTTP. Como outros cabeçalhos, os cookies devem ser enviados antes de qualquer saída do seu script (esta é uma restrição de protocolo). Isso requer que você faça chamadas para essa função antes de qualquer saída, incluindo as tags <html>e <head>, além de qualquer espaço em branco.**

Comment: Amigos, o código inteiro da página é esse que colei aqui. Não há absolutamente nada antes. Como a pergunta pode ser duplicada se todas as outras fazem referência a uma chamada no header anterior ao unset? Só se eu tirar a tag <?php :))

Comment: Woss, agradeço a preocupação, mas não é o caso de rever o sistema de autenticação: para meu uso, é mais do que suficiente. A questão é mesmo a mensagem de erro como se tivesse uma chamada de header, mas não tem. Estou vasculhando a web em português, inglês e espanhol, e não encontro nenhum caso parecido com esse. Obrigado

Comment: Jasar Orion, não há nenhuma saída para a tela. O mistério continua. Obrigado