# Erro - Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando fazer um `footer` no site com acesso ao banco para mostrar o usuário logado, mas quando logo da esse erro, já pesquisei e não consegui resolver.

meu rodapé:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
if ((!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) == TRUE) && (!isset($_SESSION['senha']) == TRUE) && (!isset($_SESSION['id']) == TRUE) && (!isset($_SESSION['perfil']) == TRUE) && (!isset($_SESSION['nome']) == TRUE)) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('location: login.php');
}

include './conexao.php';

$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$select = "SELECT pu.descricao "
        . "FROM perfil_usuario pu "
        . "INNER JOIN login lo ON lo.perfil = pu.id "
        . "WHERE lo.id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<div id="footer">
    <label id="label"><?php echo $nome . ' - ' . $linha['descricao'] ?></label>
</div>
```

Estou chamando ele assim no fim do meu content do html:

```
<?php include './rodape.php'?>
```

Se eu tirar o trecho do include './conexao.php'; ele funciona sem dar erro.

Comment: O tal conexao.php deve ter algum espaço ou outra coisa e também deve ter headers. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18812/3635

Comment: Exato, na conexão tem um `header` com `charset`, como faço pra colocar o `charset` agora?

Comment: Coloca antes do espaço que deve existir dentro do teu conexao.php, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18812/3635

Comment: a sessão e as headers devem ser iniciadas antes de qualquer output do php para a tela. caso tenha algum print ou até mesmo um espaço antes disso, este erro será exibido.