# Loop de promessas não retorna JSON em Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises, async-await

Possuo um array com os Eventos a serem pesquisados, para verificar se existe outro no mesmo dia e hora.

O código abaixo me retorna os eventos existentes sem problema, mas apenas no console.log. Preciso retornar para o Front e por enquanto não estou conseguindo.

Resumindo, meu loop não retorna o json que preciso para o front.

```
const searchEvent = async event => {
      const response = await Event.findOne({
        where: {
          [Op.or]: [
            {
              start: { [Op.between]: [event.start, event.end] },
            },
            {
              end: { [Op.between]: [event.start, event.end] },
            },
          ],
          room_id: event.room_id,
        },
      });
      return response;
    };

    const loadEvents = arrayOfEventsWithDateIniAndDateEnd.map(
      async event =>
        await searchEvent(event).then(result => console.log(result))
    );

    return res.json(loadEvents);
```

**Retorno do Insomnia:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

> ```js
> const loadEvents = arrayOfEventsWithDateIniAndDateEnd.map(
>   async event =>
>     await searchEvent(event).then(result => console.log(result))
>   );
>
> return res.json(loadEvents);
> ```

Note que você está mapeando um array de valores em um array de promessas. Lembre-se que [funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas) *sempre* retornarão uma `Promise`.

Portanto, você precisa de um meio para garantir que todas as promessas do array mapeado sejam resolvidas antes de passá-las ao método `res.json`.

Para fazer isso, basta utilizar a função `Promise.all`, que aguarda a resolução de todas as promessas do array, retornando um novo array com os valores de cada resolução.

Assim:

```js
const loadEvents = arrayOfEventsWithDateIniAndDateEnd.map(
  async event =>
    await searchEvent(event)
  );

try {
  const resolvedValues = await Promise.all(loadEvents);
  return res.json(resolvedValues);
} catch (err) {
  return res.status(500).json({
    status: 'err',
    error: err.message
  });
}
```

Não se esqueça de tratar por eventuais erros. Se uma das promessas falhar, `Promise.all` rejeitará também. [Saiba mais na documentação.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Opa @Luiz Felipe. Fiz a alteração mas não funcionou. No insomnia apresenta o erro:
**500 Internal Server Error**
[object Promise]. E no console apresenta o erro: "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client..."

Comment: Você precisa tratar eventuais rejeições. Procure utilizar `try/catch`, por exemplo. Não se esqueça que, [se uma das promessas rejeitarem, aquela retornada por `Promise.all` também será rejeitada](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#rejei%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Comment: Utilizei o try/catch, me retorna o : Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. E a função está funcionando pois consigo ver o resultado no console, quando uso o console.log.

Comment: Você deve estar definindo algum cabeçalho em outra parte da aplicação... Não tem nada a ver com o `Promise.all` (ou qualquer coisa desta pergunta ou resposta). Saiba mais sobre esse erro [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/69296).

Comment: Esse controller é novo, tem pouco código, tratei todos com "return". Mas para teste, retirei todos os res.json dele, ficando apenas a importação do Model e do sequelize com código que postei. Mesmo assim apresenta o erro.

Comment: você está certo. O problema está nas rotas condicionais que estou usando. Testei comentando e funcionou. Agora o problema é com a rota. kkkkkkk